# Splitting Letters and Numbers in Poker Data with Pandas - Best Approach?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Poker Data Analysis With Pandas. What is the best approach to split letters and numbers with no delimiters?

I am working with a data frame that contains a sample of poker hands. I have been cleaning the data to make it more manageable, but I am encountering difficulties with the following task:

One of the columns, called "Action," contains values representing actions taken during each street of the game.

For instance, in the preflop street, the value could be "`fffr225fc`," which translates to "`fold, fold, fold, raise to 225, fold, call`".

My objective is to split each action into a new row. Therefore, instead of:

```
fffr225fc
```

I would like it to be represented as:

```
f

f

f

r225

f

c
```

How would you suggest approaching this problem? What is your proposed solution?

I tried to use the code

```
df['Action'] = df['Action'].str.findall(r'\D+\d*').explode().reset_index(drop=True)
```

but it doesnt work the way it was supposed to

Maybe the problem is the argument for the function `findall()`, but I'm not figuring it out

Comment: What about `re.findall(r'(?:[fcr])(?:\d+)?', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to use a [*non-greedy*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) quantifier in your regex :

```
df = pd.DataFrame() # .. your dataframe here

out = df.assign(Action= df["Action"].str.findall("\D+?\d*")).explode("Action")
#                                                    ^------- add this
```

Ouptut :

```
print(out)

  Action
0      f
0      f
0      f
0   r225
0      f
0      c
```